# how to enable or to make an product/Services for purchase in quickbooks

Tags: c#, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I can able to add product or service for Bill in quick books but i don't have any idea about how to make it as purchasable using C# QBO3 Online SDK. The products are added but those products are not getting displayed in the drop down. I am doing this in "Enter Bill" Page. Any help would be appreciated. I am using quickbook Online Plus account.